# Square version of \in symbol?

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

The `mathabx` package provides a square version of `\subset` (namely `\sqsubset`). However I don't think there is a square version of `\in`. Does anyone know of one? If not, what is the best way to create it?

Comment: For my opinion it not exist, but you colud create a personal symbol using for example with`tikz`.

Comment: The duplicate is from 2013, and the accepted answer is either incomplete or out of date as of 2018. This operator is now in Unicode and several common packages.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. ⋿ is Unicode character U+22FF, *Z-notation bag membership*. You can `\usepackage{unicode-math}` and paste it in. The package also declares it as `\bagmember`.  It has the spacing of a relational operator.

The `stix` package likewise declares this symbol as `\bagmember`, but I highly recommend you use `unicode-math` wherever you can.  It has far better coverage, superior ability to add or substitute glyphs, and compatibility with modern fonts and technologies. As a bonus, you can copy, paste and search for symbols in both the source file and the PDF.

Comment: +1 you could perhaps copy this answer to the duplicate question as that's an old question and doesn't have a unicode-math answer currently

Comment: Left a comment there.